# Is there a way to change a <span> background image with an input files temporary image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-upload, input

I have a span which has the default background image which fills is the face of the . Once a file is selected I would like to change the background of the span to the chosen image. Is this possible?

I have the HTML:

```
<div class="one">
    <span class="two upload_image"></span>
    <input id="input_file" class="three" type="file" name="e_picture" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

My Current Js (Changes src of the upload_image class) to a selected image, not the chosen image:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.upload_image').css('background-image', 'url("http://www.thechefsdirectory.com/x/x_images/x_template/form/upload_document.png")');
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#input_file").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

This is what the input looks like:

[image]

The perfect scenario. The user clicks the input and selects a file to upload.

The background then changes from the default css background to the temporary preview.

Then if the user clicks the file again, they can change the image.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please give some constructive feedback.

Comment: What do you mean with _to a selected image, not the chosen image_? I don't understand what isn't working.

Comment: (Selected image == Chosen Image), I want to change the span background to an image that is chosen by the user through the <input type="file"/>

Comment: Set background image to `e.result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using the [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file_access).

In a nutshell, the File API allows JavaScript in the browser to access the local file system. That would allow you to load the image and display it (the examples specifically list this use case).

Comment: Boom, perfect, I used the source of that link which can be found [here](http://html5demos.com/file-api#view-source) Using the line: holder.style.background = 'url(' + event.target.result + ') no-repeat center'; Perfect answer thanks! rep++